# Rancher container taking over host IP

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, rancher

I have 2 IP addresses in my rancher host (centos): `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2`

`1.1.1.1` is the IP address I want to use to access the rancher UI and SSH into the host.

I want to use `2.2.2.2` for accessing containers for an application. I have 2 containers, one nginx and one ssh. I configured the containers to use hostport `80` mapped to `2.2.2.2:80` and `22` to hostport `2.2.2.2:22`.

I have also changed the default run command for the rancher container to listen on port `80` and `443` of IP `1.1.1.1`

If I go to my browser and access `1.1.1.1` I see rancher as expected, and if I access `2.2.2.2` I see my container app as expected.

However, if I try accessing `1.1.1.1:22` I end up connecting to the container ssh, which should be only listening to `2.2.2.2:22`.

Am I missing something here? Is this a configuration issue on the host or the container? Can the container get access to something that it shouldn't even be aware of?

**UPDATE**

Let me try to clarify the setup:

Rancher is running in a host with 2 IP addresses. When I run rancher, I execute the following command, so it becomes attached to the first IP address:

```
docker run -d --volumes-from rancher-data --restart=unless-stopped -p 1.1.1.1:80:80 -p 1.1.1.1:443:443 rancher/rancher
docker run -d --privileged --restart=unless-stopped --net=host -v /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes -v /var/run:/var/run rancher/rancher-agent:v2.1.7 --server https://rancher1.my.tld --token [token] --ca-checksum [checksum] --etcd --controlplane --worker
```

I have 4 containers configured in the rancher UI, which I want pointing to `2.2.2.2:22` and `2.2.2.2:80`, `2.2.2.2:2222` and `2.2.2.2:8080`

These are 2 environments for an application. `22` and `80` are nginx and ssh containers for the LIVE environment (sharing a data volume between them) and the same thing for `2222` and `8080`, with these being for a the QA environment. I use the ssh container to upload contents to the nginx container through the shared data volume.

I don't see a problem with this configuration, except the fact that when I configure the ssh machine to use port `22`, when I try connecting to the host ssh, I get connected to the container ssh.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a screenshot from the port mapping settings in the container: https://snag.gy/idTjoV.jpg

Container port `22` mapped to IP `2.2.2.2:222`

If I set that to `2.2.2.2:22`, SSH to host stops working, and ssh connections are established to the container instead.

Comment: Please share your docker run commands. Also can you please elaborate on what you are trying to do with SSH inside a container? I feel something is not right with SSH inside a container.

Comment: @leodotcloud updated question with more information

Comment: When launching your container from the UI, did you choose HostPort and also specify the IP address?

Comment: @leodotcloud I updated the post to include a screenshot of the port mapping configuration.